# setting up Git on a Windows server

Tags: git, version-control

I have a mac (runs OS X Lion), when I create XCode projects, there is an option to create a local `git` repository on the same machine, however, after I created a test XCode project (with its local git repository), I want XCode to push/pull changes not from GitHub, but from a Windows server (located at our local network, IP address: 10.3.3.12).
how can I set Git on this server ?

p.s. I have found many tutorials, but they sound to be outdated and hard to follow, like [this one](http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/tour.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more up-to-date guide for setting up a Git server on Windows:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2011/08/20/simple-guide-to-running-git-server-on-windows-in-local-network-kind-of.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can setup an Apache server with Smart HTTP configured to serve your Git repo - http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html

Smart HTTP is what I have found to be the easiest way for setting a Windows Git server, to be used from Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

After you setup the server, it is easier to clone the repository, and then create the xcode project in that repository.  XCode will use the repository correctly if you start the project in the same folder that you cloned.

```
git clone username@yourlocal-repos:repo.git
```